# Is there a difference in the energy produced from the hydrolysis of GTP and ATP?

Tags: biochemistry, molecular-biology

Is the energy produced from the hydrolysis of GTP greater than/less than or the same. I know that GTP can be converted to ATP through a pathway and so my thinking was that GTP would be less.

Comment: The base attached to ribose has, I guess, negligible effect on the stability of the third phosphate. So, I guess the energy released should be the same. Still looking for valid references.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

As @WYSIWYG said in comments, there is no effect of change in nitrogenous base on the third phosphate. Why? Simple, they are too far to directly influence each other's stability. See the diagram (of ATP) below from [wikipedia](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/ATP_hydrolysis):

[image: ATP hydrolysis]

and of GTP from [here](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Guanosine_triphosphate):

[image: GTP]

What one can clearly interpret from these diagrams is that there would be no effect on the energy released by hydrolysis of the third phosphate by the nitogenous base present. It will remain -30.5 kJ/mol<sup>([1](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/ATP_hydrolysis))</sup> in both cases.

Comment: You are almost certainly correct, but you do not cite an experimental value of the free energy of hydrolysis of GTP to support your statement, which I think is required. (And not so easy to find.)

Comment: You are correct, there is (probably) no citation for it. I'll  search for it tomorrow when I'll  be free :)